# dplyr recode new function

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to do this kind of evaluation with new `dplyr::recode` function?

```
1:5 = 'category1

LETTERS[1:5] = 'category2'

c(‘A’, ‘C’) = 'category3’
```

I work extensively with Household / Labour Force Survey microdata processing and would like to share with you my experience.

For instance recoding age numeric variable (1:150) into categorical variable is not so easy with `plyr::revalue` or `plyr::mapvalues`.

as you should explicitly define which number go on which category :

```
require(plyr)
my.df1 <- data.frame(age = 1:150) %>% 
            mutate(  
               age_5yrbands = age %>%
                            mapvalues(from = c(1:150) ,
                                      to = c(rep(NA, 14),
                                             rep('15-19', 5),
                                             rep('20-24', 5),
                                             rep('25-29', 5),
                                             rep('30-34', 5),
                                             rep('35-39', 5),
                                             rep('40-44', 5),
                                             rep('45-49', 5),
                                             rep('50-54', 5),
                                             rep('55-59', 5),
                                             rep('60-64', 5),
                                             rep('65+', 86)) )
)
```

so I used `car` package (recode):

```
require(car)
require(dplyr)
my.df <- data.frame(age = 1:150) %>% 
           mutate(  
             age_5yrbands = age  %>% 
                           recode("  15:19 = '15-19';
                                     20:24 = '20-24';
                                     25:29 = '25-29';
                                     30:34 = '30-34';
                                     35:39 = '35-39';
                                     40:44 = '40-44';
                                     45:49 = '45-49';
                                     50:54 = '50-54';
                                     55:59 = '55-59';
                                     60:64 = '60-64';
                                     65:150 = '65+';
                                     else = NA ",
                          as.factor.result = TRUE),
              age_10yrbands = age_5yrbands %>%
                          recode("  c('15-19', '20-24') = '15-24';
                                    c('25-29', '30-34') = '25-34';
                                    c('35-39', '40-44') = '35-44';
                                    c('45-49', '50-54') = '45-54';
                                    c('55-59', '60-64') = '55-64';
                                    '65+' = '65+';
                                    else = NA",
                           as.factor.result = TRUE)
)
```

Age could be consider as relatively simple, but when you start to play with International Standard Classification at 2 digits levels, the encoding start to be very long and risk of error very high, like occupation: ISCO88, Education: ISCED11, Economic activity ISIC4).

I could also use `cut`, but `dplyr` grammar is much better !

Comment: Can you have the ages and their relative coding in a separate table in long format? That is a table of two columns where each row has an age and its relative coding. If you can, than you can simply *join* the data table and the coding table with the function **merge**.

Comment: `dplyr` has a a new `recode` function?

I use `cut` for continuous variables like age. 

For country or education, I would create & maintain a new data frame with the recoded values. Then I would `left_join` it. It's much neater I think.

Comment: `recode` uses character strings to encode the recoding specification? That’s ab-so-lute-ly terrible. Bad function.

Comment: dplyr has new recode function on the dev version. car::recode eval a character strings which is at least readable for dummy user, not need left_join or refactor. Thanks